# How to run a custom module in saltstack

Tags: python, salt-stack

I've been dealing with saltstack for around 2 weeks, and I already can configure my salt environment, but when I try to create a custom module with python and use the following command:

```
sudo salt '*' saltutil.sync_all
```

nothing happens and my script is not replicated nor is available in none of my minions.

I try to run it whit this command:

```
sudo salt '*' change_mysql_password.change_mysql_password
```

and the output is that my script is not available

any suggestions? am I missing a step in here?

**Edit:** I have my custom module under `/srv/salt/_modules` and it matches with my master `file_roots`.

Answer (score 2):

Running saltutil.sync_all should at least generate output like

```
minion.local:
    ----------
    grains:
    modules:
    outputters:
    renderers:
    returners:
    states:
```

If thats not happening, check the logfiles of your master and minion (run in foreground for more output) for exceptions or errors regarding your module or the command itself.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `/srv/salt/top.sls` with at least a `base` environment set up?

Answer (score -1):

Check that you have configured the `extension_modules` parameter in your `master` configuration file properly.

In my case I also had to configure `module_dirs`, dont know why, but you can give it a try.